# Example of a maximal ideal in Lie algebra

Tags: lie-algebras, examples-counterexamples

Could anybody give an example of maximal ideal $M$ of a Lie algebra $L$ such that $\dim \frac{L}{M}>1$?

Actually, I'd like to know at least one example of semiprime Lie algebra, but it is not semisimple. I read several theorems about semiprime Lie algebras but no author has exhibited an example of such algebra to make sure the object of study exists.

Can anyone help me with this? Any suggestions are appreciated.

*Definition:* A Lie algebra $L$ is said to be *semiprime* if for every nonzero ideals $I$, $[I,I]\neq 0$.

Comment: As for the first question, take any semisimple Lie algebra which is not simple (say, $\mathfrak{sl}_2 \oplus \mathfrak{sl}_2$). The dimensions of $L/M$ for maximal ideals $M$ will be the dimensions of the simple summands, which are $\ge 3$. -- As for examples for prime Lie algebras, every simple Lie algebra has that property. Maybe you want a less trivial example?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg, thanks for your answer. I changed a bit the text because I want a less trivial example.

Comment: As for the new property "semiprime", it means that L contains no nonzero abelian ideal. Which (at least over fields of characteristic 0) is a well-known alternative definition of "semisimple". I wonder where you read about those "prime" or "semiprime" properties?

Comment: This properties I found in the article "Algebras of quotients of Lie algebra" by Siles Molina. Molina don't consider Lie algebras over a field, but over a commutative ring with 1. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: "[https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://webpersonal.uma.es/~MSILESM/Pub_Papers_files/S29AQLA.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwjAu8S6m4PXAhWKiZAKHVVdAJ4QFgg3MAM&usg=AOvVaw3CgwQsCHpHP5FDw7TkSvgc]"